What is the maximum span for a beam made of two 2x10s screwed and carriage-bolted together?
This is for a inside loft of our cabin so not using PT wood and just southern yellow pine from Home Depot. The beam in question runs 15-3/4'from ledger to ledger and those are single 2x10s lagged to the 5" log beam exterior on one side and a 4x8 rafter running through the interior wall of the cabin. The joints are 2x10s on 16" centers hanging on Simpson hidden hangers. The full loft dimensions are 15.75' x 10.5'.
We currently have 4x4 posts underneath the generic off-the-shelf Simpson double brackets but we are considering replacing the hangers with beefier Simpson OU410 4 x 10 Ornamental Joist Hangers and eliminating the posts altogether. If those can't support the approximate 2000lb load of the whole structure including the 3/4" Adventech and LVP flooring, we will replace the 4x4s with 6x6s for aesthetic reasons.
This week, my friend is talking with an engineer he works with out of Denver about all of this but I'm just getting mixed signals on the maximum span for 2-ply 2x10s. I'm not concerned so much if the the structure will fall if we held a WWE wrestling match on it but more so what the code requirement and load capacities are. Some say the 2x10s are good and some say 10 feet is the maximum.

10 feet is a good rule of thumb, if not bothering with span tables/weight limits to make sure.  Think most span tables will push it to 12 or 13 feet for single joists for 40 pounds per square foot.  A double joist should give a couple more feet, but as most things like this where it falling on your head is a bad day, an engineer is your best friend.

Could some people be confusing the span of joints versus beams/headers? When I look up maximum beam lengths for 2x10s, most of the results show up for joints and are vastly different in allowable distance and load.
Like this Google result from a Home Depot link:
"How far can a 2x10 beam span without support?
Larger joists can span across wider areas. For example, a 2x6 joist would have a 12-foot, 6-inch maximum span, and a 2x10 joist would have a 21-foot maximum span. Additionally, wood species and grading determines how far apart floor joists can be spaced.

A lot of it depends on the load/weight the floor is expected to hold.  I would imagine a 21 foot span will be a bit bouncy walking across it.  Not a floor I want to place a heavy couch/sofa in the middle.
